# Zip align not working when publishing Phonegap App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish my Phonegap app in Google Play Console, every time I upload my APK file, I get this error,

> You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.

I've zip aligned and jarsigned my APK with my own Key. Here are the codes below I used to zipalign and jarsign,

**Zip Align**

```
zipalign -v 4 C:\Android\android-release-unsigned.apk C:\Android\myappname-alpha.apk
```

**Jar Sign**

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore C:\Android\DevsLair.keystore C:\Android\myappname-alpha.apk DevsLairAlias
```

My Phonegap Android platform version is `6.1.2`. Am I doing something wrong here? How can I get rid of this problem and publish my app?